# Validator Framework @Min, @Max, @NotBlank not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am trying my hand in Validator ANnotations and I dont seem to have the hang of it yet

THese are my DTO

```
public class CustomerDTO {
    @NotBlank(message = "Blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 10, message = "error")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+", message = "Includes charectors not included")
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
public class UserDTO {
    @NotBlank(message = "Blank")
    @Min(value = 3, message = "minimum len")
    @Max(value = 10, message = "max len")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+", message = "Includes charectors not included")
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

THis is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/trial")
public class UserNameStringController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/nameChange")
    public void update(@Valid @RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO){
        System.out.println(customerDTO.getName());
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setName(customerDTO.getName());
        System.out.println(userDTO.getName());
    }
}
```

This is my request body

```
{
   "name": "hi"
}
```

I am able to get a valid answer for this, it doesnt raise an error or send my error messages. I dont understand why??? Someone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define in your `pom.xml` the validation dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I also wanted to ask, there is a redundancy as I have added the checks on UserDTO and CustomerDTO. I wanted to know if there is anyway I can remove one of them and ensure the validation remains. THe parameter for this method will always come in this way only.

Comment: it looks like your `UserDTO` and `CustomerDTO` classes are the same, you can delete one of them and keep the validation on the other.

Answer (score 0):

To work this you have to define Validator bean in your configuration.

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LOGGER.info("Instatntiating Bean for Message Source ");
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:" + PROPERTY_PREFIX);
    validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
    LOGGER.info("Instatntiating Bean for Message Source completed");
    return validatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding the dependency mentioned in the previous answer, but can you send some article or blogpost that is a good source to understand LocalValidatorFatoryBean and it uses